# Graphdb seem to be missing rdfs:subClassOf inference

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, graphdb, rdfs

I am using the RDFS-Plus (Optimized) ruleset. According to this: https://docs.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph/v2.2/userdoc/inferences.htm
[image]

If something is of type `owl:Class` it should be inferred it is an `rdfs:subClassof owl:Thing`.

If I run the query

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
select ?s ?p where { 
    ?s ?p owl:Thing .
}
```

I only get results for when I have *explicitly* stated that a class is an `rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing`

Can someone explain what I am missing and why this does not seem to work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the `.pie` rule files located in `$GDB_HOME/configs/rules` and found that the graphdb rulesets do not match the link in the question. The least complex ruleset (according to https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/rules-optimisations.html#hints-on-optimizing-graphdb-s-rulesets) that provides the functionality needed is `owl2-ql-optimized`.